# Deserializing JSON data and displaying C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the following data and display them using C#:

```
{  
   "_links":{  
      "self":{  
         "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426/teams"
      },
      "competition":{  
         "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/426"
      }
   },
   "count":"20",
   "teams":[  
      {  
         "_links":{  
            "self":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/322"
            },
            "fixtures":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/322/fixtures"
            },
            "players":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/322/players"
            }
         },
         "name":"Hull City FC",
         "code":"HUL",
         "shortName":"Hull",
         "squadMarketValue":"122,250,000 €",
         "crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/a/a9/Hull_City_AFC.svg"
      },
      {  
         "_links":{  
            "self":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/338"
            },
            "fixtures":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/338/fixtures"
            },
            "players":{  
               "href":"http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/338/players"
            }
         },
         "name":"Leicester City FC",
         "code":"LCFC",
         "shortName":"Foxes",
         "squadMarketValue":"205,300,000 €",
         "crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have generated these classes:

```
public class Team
{
    public Links2 _links { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string shortName { get; set; }
    public string squadMarketValue { get; set; }
    public string crestUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Links _links { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Team> teams { get; set; }
}
```

I then tried to parse and display the data:

```
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
{
    dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    foreach (var obj in jsonObj.teams)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(obj.name);
    }
}
```

However it seems to break when entering the foreach loop. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong? An unhandled exception error appears.

Comment: That json you posted isn't even valid. Let's start by seeing the real json string you need to deserialize. Also add the error or the exception you are getting.

Comment: Try its rootobject objs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootobject>(json.ToString)

Comment: You should decide if you want to use your typed classes *or* a dynamic object.

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I have updated the json format for you, are you still getting the same error now?

Comment: No thank you @EugeneKomisarenko.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct only, unless you update your question with the error.

Okay, let me tell you one more way to do it in .net. You can also use Linq

1. Reference `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` to your project.

And add the following code

```
dynamic jsonObj = JObject.Parse(your_JSON_string);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj.teams)

{
   Console.WriteLine(obj.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the team names from your list of teams you have to query the list.

```
RootObject jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj.teams.Select(x => x.name))
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(obj);
}
```